# I am not able to see the grid view in my Bookmark which extends Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am facing an issue the problem is I can see the `Fragment` but not the 
`GridView` which I have there created, in the `LogCat` no error nothing but somehow the code it is not working.
But if I remove `GridView` from `bookmark.xml` and only leave a `TextView` than I can show the `TextView`
I am trying to reach a `GridView` into a `Fragment`.
This is my code.

**Fragment**

```
public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {
    View paramView;
    public FragmentBookmark() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, container, false);
        return paramView;
    }

}
```

**This is the Main Activity**

```
 ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentExplore(), "");
 adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentBookmark(), "");
 adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentStore(), "");
 mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

**This is the xml for Bookmark Fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you used `.setAdapter?`

Comment: What do you think .setAdapter because I am new in android ? can you explain more or edit my code

Comment: If you are new, I would suggest you to use `RecyclerView.` because `GridView` is  old.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if you have any suggestion what to do please edit my code or make an answer

Comment: you can have a look my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using framelayout

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<GridView
    android:id = "@+id/gvList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `adapter` to your `GridView` as only `GridView` will never show anything as it is a simple ViewGroup.. Also rather than using `GridView` try to use `RecyclerView` in grid mode. Below is a simple tutorial you can follow-
[RecyclerView as GridView with GridLayoutManager](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/m_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**grid_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="Category" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Adapter:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> myNameList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> categoryInfo) {
        mContext = context;
        myNameList = categoryInfo;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String myName = myNameList.get(position);
        holder.tvName.setText(myName);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myNameList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvName;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        }
    }
}
```

**In your `Activity` or `Fragment:`**

```
Context mContext = this;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.m_recyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3));

ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();
nameArray.add("name 1");
nameArray.add("name 2");
nameArray.add("name 3");
nameArray.add("name 4");

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(mContext, nameArray));
```

Comment: The Activity what you have write in which of my java class I need to implement and the @dimens from xml where I need to import because the are unknow ?

Comment: in `onCreateView` method of `FragmentBookmark.` or in `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`

Comment: what data you entered in **yourStringArrayList?**

Comment: Nothing, but I have another errors for example @dimens and it is oke where I put the Acitivity shows me only errors can you please change all my code with your actual code and see if it works.

Comment: I removed dimensions and update answer. I updated code for `.setAdapter` also. check it now and tell me what errors you are getting.

Comment: I have errors in the MainActivity in this line. mContext cannot resolve mContext

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3));
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(mContext, nameArray));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184090/discussion-between-rumit-patel-and-spritzig).